# Limit total upload size of all the files in uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm using uploadify to upload files. I would like to throw error and stop submitting/uploading the form if the total upload size of all files are greater than 10MB.

I browsed the document of uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/ and found "fileSizeLimit" which limits file size of a single file. But I want total upload size of all files together.

Can some one suggest me how to do this?? Below is my code

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({    
    'formData' : {
        'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
        'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
    },
    'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',

    'auto'     : false,        
    'buttonText' : 'Upload Document',
    'fileTypeExts' : '<?php echo $allowedFileExts; ?>',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '10MB',
    'onQueueComplete' : function(event,data) {            
        document.someForm.submit();
        document.someForm.reset();
    }
});
});
</script>
<form id="someForm" name="someForm" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true"/>
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel','*');">Clear Queue</a>
<input onclick="$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*')" type="button" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" />
<div id="queue"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Take a global variable there and then add sizes

Comment: hey ankit. thx for your quick response. I had tried ur suggestion. I can trigger error. but couldn't stop submitting/uploading the form. I'd also tried to hide the submit button when total size is above 10MB. But I want to show submit button always as file uploading is not mandatory on my form.

Comment: Hi there, I can't actually estimate what they return in the library but you probably go through the link below using onselect. Check what you have in console.log(file) under file's object. (Most of the time you'll be able to get array of files + size). Keep all the sizes in array and sum up. http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onselect/

Comment: Hi aditya can you post your tried code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast, I found my own solution for my issue. Thanks all for your support. My code is below. might be helpful for someone.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
var totalfilesize = 0;
$(function() {
var queueSize = 0;
$('#file_upload').uploadify({    
    'formData' : {
        'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
        'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
    },
    'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',

    'auto'     : false,        
    'buttonText' : 'Upload Document',
    'fileTypeExts' : '<?php echo $allowedFileExts; ?>',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '10MB',        
    'onSelectError' : function() {
        alert('The file ' + file.name + ' returned an error and was not added to the queue.');
    },
    'onSelect' : function(file){
        queueSize++;
        $('#queuesize').val(queueSize);
        totalfilesize = totalfilesize+file.size;
        chkfilesize(totalfilesize);
    },
    'onCancel' : function(file) { 
        queueSize--;
        $('#queuesize').val(queueSize);
        totalfilesize = totalfilesize-file.size;
        chkfilesize(totalfilesize);             
    },
    'onUploadStart' : function(file) {            
    },
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        //$("#response").html(data);            
        $('#uploadedfiles').val($('#uploadedfiles').val() + data);            
    },
    'onQueueComplete' : function(event,data) {            
        document.someForm.submit();
        $('#queuesize').val('0');
        $('#uploadedfiles').val('');            
        document.someForm.reset();

    }
});
 });

function chkfilesize(totalfilesize){
if(totalfilesize > 10485760){        
    $('#fileerror').html('File Size exceeds 10MB');
    $('#fileerror').show();
}else{        
    $('#fileerror').html('');
    $('#fileerror').hide();
}

}
function submitForm() { 
var validatefileresp = validatefile();    
if(validatefileresp === true){
    $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*');
}
}

function validatefile(){  
if ($("#queuesize").val() == 0) {
    document.someForm.submit();
    $('#uploadedfiles').val('');
    $('#queuesize').val('0');        
    document.someForm.reset();        
}else{
    if(totalfilesize > 10485760){
        $('#fileerror').html('File Size exceeds 10MB');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}

}
</script>
<form id="someForm" name="someForm" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
First name: <input name="fname" type="text" /><br>
Last name: <input name="lname" type="text" /><br><br><br>
Upload only doc,pdf,docx,xls,xlsx,txt,rtf format files<br>
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true"/>
<input type="hidden" name="uploadedfiles" id="uploadedfiles" value=""  />
<input type="hidden" name="queuesize" id="queuesize" value="0" />
<br><br>
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel','*');">Clear Queue</a>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input onclick="javascript:submitForm();" type="button" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" />
<div id="fileerror"></div>
<div id="queue"></div>

<div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sizeLimit`

Look at this line **

```
else if (d.type ==="File Size")
     alert(c.name+' '+d.type+' Limit: '+Math.round(d.sizeLimit/1024)+'KB');**
```

in:

```
 onError: function (a, b, c, d) {
         if (d.status == 404)
            alert('Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: '+'<?= getcwd() ?>');
         else if (d.type === "HTTP")
            alert('error aaa'+d.type+": "+d.status);
         else if (d.type ==="File Size")
            alert(c.name+' '+d.type+' Limit: '+Math.round(d.sizeLimit/1024)+'KB');
         else
            alert('error '+d.type+": "+d.text);
```